# Vuetify 3 v-form submitting even if not valid

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm using v-form (Vuetify 3) like this:

```
    <v-form @submit.prevent="submit">
        <v-row>
            <v-col cols="12" md="6">
                <v-text-field v-model="name" :label="$t('register.name')" :rules="[required]"></v-text-field>
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="12" md="6">
                <v-text-field v-model="email" :label="$t('register.email')" :rules="[required, validMail]" required></v-text-field>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    
        <v-btn @click="register()">Submit</v-btn>
    </v-form>
```

Then in methods I have these functions:

```
required: function (value) {
    if (value) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return 'required field';
    }
},
validMail: function () {
    if (/long regex/.test(this.email)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return 'invalid mail';
    }
},
register() {
    if(this.password != this.repeatpassword) {
        alert("bad");
        return
    }
    try {
        axios.post() // sending data to server
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

The problem is that, the form submits even if some of the fields is not valid. I've also tried:

- using rules - that's how it's stated in the documentation and how I've tried to implement the validation at first. The code with methods I've provided here is just one of my desperate attempts to make it work, leading to no result.
- validation via ref - setting `ref="form"` and then split `register()` method to two blocks using

```
    if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
        axios.post()
    } else {
        //don't post
    }
```

All of these attempts have the same result: input form get validated (red border and message for user appears)  but the form behaves as if validation rules have no effect on the code executed in `register()` function.

Thanks for any help or tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control the validness of a form with the prop **model-value** (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-form/#props-model-value). This is by default false until all the rules of the inputs are ok. So for example you can do the following:

```html
<v-form v-model="isFormValid" @submit.prevent="register">
    <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12" md="6">
            <v-text-field v-model="name" :label="$t('register.name')" :rules="[required]"></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="12" md="6">
            <v-text-field v-model="email" :label="$t('register.email')" :rules="[required, validMail]" required></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-btn type="submit">Submit</v-btn>
</v-form>
```

Then you need to declare the reactive variable isValidForm on your data section (or script setup if you use Composition API):

```js
data: () => ({
    // Your other data here
    isFormValid: false,
}),
```

And then modify your register method a little bit:

```js
register() {
    if (this.isFormValid) {
        try {
            axios.post() // sending data to server
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
}
```